# How to run Ook!? (VS Language Integration)

Tags: visual-studio, vsx

I downloaded the [Ook!](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ookLanguage) source, opened the `.csproj` and ran it in debug mode. The VS Experimental Instance fires up as expected, but now I can't figure out how to get to a blank code file so I can actually try writing in Ook! I don't see "Ook!" in any of the project templates.

Also, if anyone has a link to the Ook! video tutorial, I'd appreciate it. Can't seem to find it anymore.

Comment: I'm surprised there weren't any previous [ook] questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the Ook language service is geared towards files with a .ook extension, just create a text file, change the extension to .ook and open it in the Visual Studio experimental instance.

There's also a [video about this on Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/VSIPMarketing/VSX212-Adding-a-Language-Service-into-Visual-Studio-2010), is that the one you were looking for?

Comment: Oh...it even came with a `test.ook`! I didn't see it in the list of file types either, and VS doesn't let you type an extension when creating a new file, so I was confused. Thanks! And yes! That is exactly the video I was looking for.